# Stripe Grails configuration per locale

Tags: grails, configuration, localization, locale

Is there a way in Grails to stripe the config by locale?

eg like this:

```
locale {
    fr-FR {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.mysite.fr"
    }
    en-GB {
        grails.serverURL = "http://www.mysite.co.uk"
    }
}
```

We are starting to internationalise our site for multiple country/language and some configuration will have to be country specific.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the configuration values are strings (as above) you could put them in the `message*.properties` files instead of `Config.groovy`. You can then use either the `messageSource` Spring bean or the [message](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html) tag to retrieve the values for the current Locale.

### Update

Further to the comment below about mixing config information in resource bundles, an alternative is to do it programatically - remember Config.groovy is a .groovy file, so you can mix code with your configuration data. Something like the following should work:

```
locale {    
  def serverUrls = [Locale.FRANCE: "http://www.mysite.fr", 
            Locale.UK: "http://www.mysite.co.uk"]

  def currentLocale = org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder.locale
  def serverlUrl = serverUrls[currentLocale]
  assert serverUrl, "no serverUrl found for Locale $currentLocale"    

  grails.serverURL = serverUrl
}
```

If you have several config parameters that you want to vary by Locale, something like the following would be neater

```
def currentLocale = org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder.locale

switch (currentLocale) {
  case Locale.FRANCE:
    // config params for France
  break;
  case Locale.UK:
    // config params for UK
  break;        
}
```

Comment: In that case you would mix config information in resource bundles which will work but will be messy. I guess we'll have to build our own locale config resolver :)